# vba/excel - populate cells in sheet1 from values in sheet2 based on user input into cells on sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a generic excel file to help demonstrate what I'm looking to do. The file I've named Tool.xlsm contains two worksheets; Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Sheet1 will be designed to have a few fields which will accept user input. Sheet2 will be hidden from the user, but will contain the various drop down list selection options and their corresponding descriptions which should be displayed in another cell on Sheet1 when a specific code is selected. Additionally, Sheet2 will contain numerous ID#s in one column, and their corresponding usernames in the next column. The purpose of this is for the user to be able quickly associate an ID# with user it belongs to.

Here is what I have so far...I doubt I'm going about it as efficiently as I should be, but I'd greatly appreciate your all's expertise!

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Based on selected value of C1, show corresponding message in J1'
'Can this be done by simply referencing the code descriptions in sheet2?'

If Range("C1") = "code 1" Then
    Range("J1") = "code 1 description"
End If

If Range("C1") = "code 2" Then
    Range("J1") = "code 2 description"
End If

'End of code selection'
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()

'Based on ID# entered into C3, display corresponding name in J1 (Sheet2 contains ID#s with corresponding names)'
'There has to be an esier way to loop through 1000s of records and display corresponding ID# and Person''s name'
'Rather than assigning Person 1, to Range J1, I should be able to just reference the cell Sheet2!E3 but that doesn''t seem to work'

If Range("C3") = "1001" Then
    Range("J1") = "Person 1"
End If

If Range("C3") = "34349090" Then
    Range("J1") = "Person 83"
End If

'End ID# search'
End Sub

Sub Button3_Click()

'Clear unlocked cells'

End Sub
```

[my file in dropbox](http://db.tt/tfQi0PDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the worksheet_change event. Kindly set rngFindCode & rngFindCode1 range accordingly to refer to your data in sheet2.

Below is the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$C$1" And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then

        Dim rngFindCode As Range '
        Dim cellCode As Range

        Set rngFindCode = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C100")    ' Refers to range where code is in sheet 2
        Set cellCode = rngFindCode.Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

        If Not cellCode Is Nothing Then
            Range("J1").Value = cellCode.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If

    ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$3" And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then

        Dim rngFindCode1 As Range '
        Dim cellCode1 As Range

        Set rngFindCode1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1:E100")    'Refers to range where name is
        Set cellCode1 = rngFindCode1.Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

        If Not cellCode1 Is Nothing Then
            Range("J1").Value = cellCode1.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If

    Else
        Range("J1").Value = ""
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! I will give it a try today and post the results!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I can't seem to make it work.

Please check out my file http://db.tt/tfQi0PDK and see if it can be made to function per your advice.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2292941 i have added the code to your file which can be downloaded from this link http://sdrv.ms/ZJ4jAh

Comment: Much appreciated! Works like a charm and now I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

To your queries:

> Can this be done by simply referencing the code descriptions in sheet2?

Yes. You can use `VLOOKUP` formula for this.

Likewise, you could use the `VLOOKUP` formula to return the names based on the IDs.

E.g., assume your usernames are in column K and ID's in column J:

On sheet 1, assuming the ID in cell C3, enter the formula: `=VLOOKUP(C3, Sheet2!$J$K, 2, False)`

Comment: I completely forgot about the VLOOKUP function and when I went to implement it, was getting #ref errors. A little toying around and I figured it out! Thanks for your input!

Comment: @David a little syntax error, `vlookup` should end in `2, FALSE)`